# Android volley to handle redirect

Tags: android, android-volley

I recently started to use Volley lib from Google for my network requests. One of my requests get error 301 for redirect, so my question is that can volley handle redirect somehow automatically or do I have to handle it manually in `parseNetworkError` or use some kind of `RetryPolicy`here?

Thanks.

Comment: In case you're interested in the opposite case (don't want volley to handle redirects automatically) check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25887160/369317

Comment: Thanks @DenisKniazhev! That is exactly what I was googling :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I fixed it catching the http status 301 or 302, reading redirect url and setting it to request then throwing expection which triggers retry.

Edit: Here are the main keys in volley lib which i modified:

- Added method public void `setUrl(final String url)` for class `Request`
- In class BasicNetwork is added check for redirection after // Handle cache validation, `if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) || statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY)`, there I read the redirect url with `responseHeaders.get("location")`, call `setUrl` with request object and throw error
- Error get's catched and it calls `attemptRetryOnException`
- You also need to have `RetryPolicy` set for the `Request` (see `DefaultRetryPolicy` for this)

Comment: Did you modify the Volley source code for this or does the API support it already? Please share code examples for other people running into the same problem

Comment: I edited my answer to show they key points for the redirection.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/samkirton/android-volley for a fork of volley with the redirect fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and your source code because I didn't found anything else working. My problem was with the NetworkImageView and your answer solves everything

Comment: responseHeaders.get("Location") not responseHeaders.get("location")

Answer (score 35):

Replace your url like that  url.replace("http", "https");

for example:
if your url looking like that :  "http://graph.facebook......."  than
it should be like             :  "https://graph.facebook......."

it works for me

Comment: Non-english speaking in stackoverflow is not good. But "Kime ne amk?".

Comment: haha... That worked like a charm ! I have experienced a similar issue with HttpURLConnection in another project. The same fix worked for that as well.

Comment: This is off subject. The server might not even offer SSL. This is a one time specualtion, that happened to work.

Answer (score 19):

If you dont want to modify the Volley lib you can catch the 301 and manually re-send the request.

In your GsonRequest class implement deliverError and create a new Request object with the new Location url from the header and insert that to the request queue.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void deliverError(final VolleyError error) {
    Log.d(TAG, "deliverError");

    final int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
    // Handle 30x 
    if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM == status || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
        final String location = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
        Log.d(TAG, "Location: " + location);
        final GsonRequest<T> request = new GsonRequest<T>(method, location, jsonRequest, this.requestContentType, this.clazz, this.ttl, this.listener, this.errorListener);
        // Construct a request clone and change the url to redirect location.
        RequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

This way you can keep updating Volley and not have to worry about things breaking.

Comment: Thanks, You save my time.

Answer (score 7):

Like many others, I was simply confused about why Volley wasn't following redirects automatically. By looking at the source code I found that while Volley will set the redirect URL correctly on its own, it won't actually follow it unless the request's retry policy specifies to "retry" at least once. Inexplicably, the default retry policy sets `maxNumRetries` to 0. So the fix is to set a retry policy with 1 retry (10s timeout and 1x back-off copied from default):

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1.0f))
```

For reference, here is the source code:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new retry policy.
 * @param initialTimeoutMs The initial timeout for the policy.
 * @param maxNumRetries The maximum number of retries.
 * @param backoffMultiplier Backoff multiplier for the policy.
 */
public DefaultRetryPolicy(int initialTimeoutMs, int maxNumRetries, float backoffMultiplier) {
    mCurrentTimeoutMs = initialTimeoutMs;
    mMaxNumRetries = maxNumRetries;
    mBackoffMultiplier = backoffMultiplier;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom implementation of `RetryPolicy` that only "retries" in the event of a 301 or 302.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: FYI: The default retry policy was set to 0 to "prevent some potential problems": https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/commit/cee2e78731f6c74cac13de5070e2609f61db848c

Comment: FYI FYI, another possible clue to redirects not working is this "recent" (2015/12/04) fix in the official upstream repo, that apparently has not made it in to the unofficial downstream github mirror repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/f0bc25d83ddceccd61c2c11a4fa71b9157290363%5E1..f0bc25d83ddceccd61c2c11a4fa71b9157290363/

Comment: With all respect and no downvote, please note that request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1.0f)); doesnt magically handle redirects. Creating a custom implementation is half way towards solving the issue, and no error handling was shown in that case.

Answer (score 5):

End up doing a merge of what most @niko and @slott answered:

```
// Request impl class
// ...

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        super.deliverError(error);

        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage(), error);

        final int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
        // Handle 30x
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM ||
                status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP ||
                status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
            final String location = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Location: " + location);
            }
            // TODO: create new request with new location
            // TODO: enqueue new request
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrl() {
        String url = super.getUrl();

        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            url = "http://" + url; // use http by default
        }

        return url;
    }
```

It worked well overriding `StringRequest` methods.

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Volley supports redirection without any patches, no need for a separate fork

Explanation:
Volley internally uses `HttpClient` which by default follows 301/302 unless specified otherwise

From: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/httpagent.html

ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS='http.protocol.handle-redirects':  defines whether redirects should be handled automatically. This parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Boolean. If this parameter is not set HttpClient will handle redirects automatically.

Comment: For me its handling some automatically but some its reported unexpected response 302 and failing.

Comment: 'Volley internally uses HttpClient' - that's not accurate, it uses HttpClient only only with API < 9 and uses HTTPUrlConnection otherwise (which got replaced with Okhttp's impl in kit-kat)

Comment: I'm on Lollipop and latest Volley and I'm getting "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 for ...". So something is not working. I can handle this in Request.deliverError but I'd rather that it was transparent.

Comment: The HttpURLConnection‘s follow redirect is just an indicator, in fact it won’t help you to do the “real” http redirection, you still need to handle it manually.

Answer (score 2):

ok, im a bit late to the game here, but i've recently been trying to achieve this same aspect, so https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483037/2423312 is the best one, given that you are willing to fork volley and maintain it and the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566737/2423312 - I'm not sure how this even worked.This one is spot on though : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454312/2423312. But its actually adding a new request object to the `NetworkDipatcher`'s queue, so you'll have to notify the caller as well somehow, there is ***one dirty way*** where you can do this by not modifying the request object + changing the field "mURL", PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS IS DEPENDENT ON YOUR IMPLEMENTATION OF VOLLEY'S `RetryPolicy.java` INTERFACE AND HOW YOUR CLASSES EXTENDING `Request.java` CLASS ARE, here you go : **welcome REFLECTION**

```
Class volleyRequestClass = request.getClass().getSuperclass();
                        Field urlField = volleyRequestClass.getDeclaredField("mUrl");
                        urlField.setAccessible(true);
                        urlField.set(request, newRedirectURL);
```

**Personally I'd prefer cloning volley though**. Plus looks like volley's example `BasicNetwork` class was designed to fail at redirects : https://github.com/google/volley/blob/ddfb86659df59e7293df9277da216d73c34aa800/src/test/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetworkTest.java#L156 so i guess they arent leaning too much on redirects, feel free to suggest/edit. Always looking for good way..

Answer (score 0):

I am using volley:1.1.1 with https url though the request was having some issue. On digging deeper i found that my request method was getting changed from POST to GET due to redirect (permanent redirect 301). I am using using nginx and in server block i was having a rewrite rule that was causing the issue.

So in short everything seems good with latest version of volley. My utility function here-

```
public void makePostRequest(String url, JSONObject body, final AjaxCallback ajaxCallback) {
    try {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, body, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(LOG, response.toString());
                ajaxCallback.onSuccess(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(LOG, error.toString());
                ajaxCallback.onError(error);
            }
        });
        singleton.getRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d(LOG, "Exception makePostRequest");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// separate file
public interface AjaxCallback {
    void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
    void onError(VolleyError error);
}
```