# Volley Library gives unexpected response code 302

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-volley

I am developing an app which has features of login via facebook and gmail.
To load image from facebook and gmail, I am using volley.

For gmail, it is working fine but for fb it gives me an error :

```
  E/Volley﹕ [380] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 302 for http://graph.facebook.com/831173210283387/picture?type=large
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481964/android-volley-to-handle-redirect), but nothing happend

Code snippet:

```
ImageLoader.ImageCache imageCache = new BitmapLruCache()
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext), imageCache);
imageLoader.get(pic_url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.profile,
                R.drawable.ic_user, R.drawable.ic_user));
```

I  read some stack overflow **answer** and according to this I also tried :

```
HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
pic_url.replace("https", "http");
Log.d("Photo url", pic_url);
```

Here is my facebook photo url

http://graph.facebook.com/831173210283387/picture?type=large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve redirect issue try this.You will get image url in image variable.

```
//loginBtn = Facebook login button

loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (user != null) {

                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        Log.i("AccessToken", session.getAccessToken());

                    }

                    String image = "";
                    String id = user.getId();
                    try {
                        URL image_path = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                + id + "/picture?type=large");
                        image = image_path + "";
                        Log.i("image::> ", image_path + "");

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                //ELSE PART
                }
            }
        });
```

Volley throws 302 when the supplied URL redirects to another url. You provided graph url of facebook in Volley, when you open that url in browser it will redirect you to another url.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try by adding "s" in your base URL like : https

**In short if replace your URL** 
http ---> https
OR
https ---> http

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same answer in multiple old questions. Flag as duplicate if you think they are. Another same answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435354/965146