# Android: HttpUrlConnection object returns error 301 after connection

Tags: android, redirect, httpurlconnection, asynctaskloader

I'm trying to connect to a web API using a URL. However, I get a **301 error from the server (Moved Permanently)**, although the provided URL works very well with no errors when I try it in my browser.

Here is the code that builds the URL:

```
 public Loader<List<Earthquake>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String minMagnitude = sharedPrefs.getString(
                getString(R.string.settings_min_magnitude_key),
                getString(R.string.settings_min_magnitude_default));

        String orderBy = sharedPrefs.getString(
                getString(R.string.settings_order_by_key),
                getString(R.string.settings_order_by_default)
        );

        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(USGS_REQUEST_URL);
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("format", "geojson");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("limit", "10");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("minmag", minMagnitude);
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("orderby", orderBy);
        Log.i ("the uri is ", uriBuilder.toString());
        return new EarthquakeLoader(this, uriBuilder.toString());
    }
```

Here is the code that tries to connect to the resource represented by the URL:

```
private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        Log.i("The received url  is " , url +"");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode()); //this log returns 301
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
                // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
                // could be thrown.
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

I could know that the connection returns status code of 301 from the log provided in the case when the status code is not 200. I have also logged the generated URL, I copied it from the logcat and tried it in my browser and it worked well. Here is the built URL: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&limit=10&minmag=6&orderby=magnitude

I checked this question: [Android HttpURLConnection receives HTTP 301 response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845854/android-httpurlconnection-receives-http-301-response-code) but it wasn't clear to me what is the solution for the problem.

Can you please help me identify and solve the problem?

**UPDATE**: As **greenapps** indicated in his comment, the connection is done through **https**. That comment identified the problem and helped me fix the code.

In my code, the string I used to build the basic URL, had the protocol value as http not https, it was:

```
private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query";
```

After reading **greenapps** comment, I just changed the protocol part in the string to https, so it became:

```
 private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL =
            "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query";
```

That solved the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you cluck your http link here you will see that the browser shows a https page. You better use that url directly as there is redirection now.

Comment: @greenapps thank you for your comment! Your comment helped me figure out the solution. As you said it's using https, I checked the base string I'm using to build the initial URL and I found that I'm using http instead, I just modified that to https, and it worked very well. Thanks a lot. You can post that as an answer if you want, I'll then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click your http link here you will see that the browser shows a https page. You better use that url directly as there is redirection now.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the address http to https transferred.
To avoid this, you need to convert the request address to https.