# accessing a password protected URL in android using volley library

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have protected some hosted files with a password to avoid any unknow access but I don't know how to directly access these files from my application , I am using Volley library and I tried this :

```
    private static final String URL = "http://user:password@mywebsite.com/file/json/";

public static void getData(final Context context) {

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                String somedata= response.getString("data");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          //  Toast.makeText(context, "Error Loading Data\n Please Restart App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

> I realised that my app doesn't fetch data from my json file , but when I
>   access the URL above from browser , it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your password into Url. `Volley` supported all Http methods. You should use `Post` or `Put` methods

```
new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
 ...
}
```

It seems your URL is incorrect or you are using redirection. Because of the result code, chrome auto calls a new url. Apart of these browser automatically set the port 80 if port is not defined.
Also pay attention on your back end side

see [Android volley to handle redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481964/android-volley-to-handle-redirect)

Comment: URL has a specific structure host://domain:port/path?query_params.
Instead of port number you had passed  password@mywebsite.com