# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

So i´m trying to login on my app and when i click the login button after inserting the username and password this error shows up in the android studio at the run tab on the bottom toolbar in the left corner:

```
E/Volley: [11996] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 301 "MYURL"
```

with my site link and nothing more.
you can learn more about the error HTTP 301 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)!
Here is my code:

## login.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class login extends Fragment{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
            final EditText etUtilizador = mView.findViewById(R.id.etUtilizador);
            final EditText etPassword = mView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
            final Button btLogin = mView.findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
            Button btlink = mView.findViewById(R.id.btlink);
            btlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), registar.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(registerIntent);
                }
            });
            btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String username = etUtilizador.getText().toString();
                    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                    Response.Listener<String> responselistener=new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse= null;
                            try {
                                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                                if (success) {
                                    String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                    int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                                    Intent intent;
                                    intent = new Intent(getContext(), utilizador.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                    intent.putExtra("age", age);
                                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                    login.this.startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                            .create()
                                            .show();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    loginrequest loginRequest = new loginrequest(username, password, responselistener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    queue.add(loginRequest);
                }
            });
            return mView;
        }
    }
```

## loginrequest.java

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class loginrequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://elabora.pt/login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public loginrequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

If you need more classes or the android manifest comment below and i edit the post.

I already have the login.php to connect to the database at the file manager and everything.

If you can help me understanding why this error is showing up i would be gratefull.

Comment: `this error shows up:` Where does it show up? Where did you see/find it?

Comment: ??????????? What is a run tab? And can we see that corner? What are you expecting? And who is putting that error message there?

Comment: at the bottom of android studio you have the TODO tab and at the left of TODO tab you have the Run tab

Comment: Isnt there more in the logcat? And what does 301 mean?

Comment: thats what im asking m8

Comment: You can easily google for that http error code and tell us.

Comment: no one has the same error only errors 500 and 400

Comment: ????????????? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: i thought you were telling me to search for solutions

Comment: You should have told us at the start of your post what this error -status code-  means. And further if you understand the error and what you would like to do with it.

Comment: it is at the beggining of the post i just want to login into the app but after putting my information and clicking the login button nothing happens i checked everything and what i found was the error that is specified above i don´t know how the error works so i´m asking for somebody to teach me how to fix

Comment: if i knew the answer i wouldn't be here

Comment: if you can explain me why this error is showing up i would be thankfull.

Comment: Well what does 301 mean? it is still not in your post.

Comment: i read a post about it but i still dont understand so i'm not going to talk about what i dont know

Comment: What does 301 mean? I gave you a link where you can find the meaning of all http status codes. So why dont you use it?

Comment: i read it i didnt understood it

Comment: You dont have to understand it at the moment. You should only tell us what you found for 301 in that document.

Comment: just found the answer
it was because my domain is protected and i was trying to access the http not the https

Comment: Interesting error message then.

Comment: i think it was because i changed the domain from http to https while i had the code of the login in the same file manager and it admited that the url changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android volley to handle redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481964/android-volley-to-handle-redirect)

Answer (score 13):

HTTP code 301 means "moved permanently". This means the URL you're trying to reach is no longer there. I had the same problem when my site implemented SSL. They redirected all request from http:// to https:// using an .htaccess file in the server, so the address in the Android app had to be changed accordingly, since it's not going to accept the redirection. You should change your LOGIN_REQUEST_URL variable to:

```
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "https://elabora.pt/login.php";
```

Hope this helps (it did solve my problem, though)

Comment: Thanks, Solved http >> https,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `Unexpected response code 301`

I was using https://example.com but it was redirecting to https://`www.`example.com via .htaccess
Changing to https://www.example.com in the app code solved my problem.

Try to open the url in the browser here you can see the exactly redirected URL copy this to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a http folder in your host or sever instead of auto redirect to https when you use volley.
It seems Volley can not handle https request.